# Jquery, Update JSON objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Hi I´m having a hard time updating my objects in my temporary array for JSON Objects.

Main goal is to:

1. Add Objects that are not prev. already in map_Markers array.
2. Update position if Object is present with same ID
3. Remove marker from map_Marker Array if JSON is without it.

This is my JSON output and its changing alot depending on user input

```
{
    "markers": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "Area": "SomeArea1",
        "Status": "on",
        "Latitude": 58.96674,
        "Longitude": 16.204277,
        "Class": "A",
        "Time": "2016-03-12 00:21"
    }, {
        "ID": "3",
        "Area": "SomeArea",
        "Status": "off",
        "Latitude": 59.000351,
        "Longitude": 16.227819,
        "Class": "A",
        "Time": "2016-03-12 00:22"
    }]
}
```

JS

```
var loadMarkers = function () {
    $.getJSON('map/map_json.php', function (data) {
        $.each(data.markers, function (i, index) {

            console.log("i =" + i + " Index =" + index.ID);

            if (map_Markers[i].ID === index.ID) {
                console.log("Updating marker position!");
                map_Markers[i].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(index.Latitude, index.Longitude));

            } else if (map_Markers[i].ID != index.ID) {
                console.log("Remove Marker!");
                map_Markers.splice(i, 1);

            } else {
                console.log("Creating new Marker!");
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(index.Latitude, index.Longitude);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: index.Area,
                    id: index.ID
                });
                console.log(index.ID);
                map_Markers.push(marker);
            } //If


        }); //each loop
        console.log("map_Marker Array : " + map_Markers.length + " Object");
        console.log(map_Markers);
    }); //getJSON
}
```

Any help and maby a fiddle would be helpful.

Thanks!